# How to project list of objects into nested object list

Tags: c#, linq

Need to get a list of DeliveryObjects but only one per truck# with its list of orders, instead of one Delivery per order.

Result im gettting is not projecting the grouped orders into one delivery

[image]

```
void Main()
{
    // project a list of orders into List<Delivery>
    List<Order> olist = new List<UserQuery.Order>();
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred1", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-12), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob1", TruckNo="A1231" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred2", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-22), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob1", TruckNo="A1231" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred3", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-21), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob2", TruckNo="A1232" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred4", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob3", TruckNo="A1233" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred5", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-13), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob4", TruckNo="A1234" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred6", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob4", TruckNo="A1234" });                      
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred7", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-11), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob5", TruckNo="A1235" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred8", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob6", TruckNo="A1236" });
    olist.Add(new Order{CustomerName = "Fred9", TargetDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8), DeliveryWeight = 23.34M,DriverName = "Bob6", TruckNo="A1236" });

    olist.Dump();
    List<Delivery> delvlist = (from a in olist
        group a by new {a.TruckNo}
        into b
        from c in b
        select new Delivery()
        {
            RefNo = c.TruckNo,
            orders = b.ToList()
        }).ToList();

    delvlist.Dump();                                
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Delivery {

    public string RefNo { get; set; }
    public List<Order> orders { get; set;}
}

public class Order{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal DeliveryWeight { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string TruckNo { get; set; }
}
```

**[edit]** I think this gets it?

```
List<Delivery> delvlist = (from a in olist
    group a by new {a.TruckNo}
    into b
    select new Delivery()
    {
        RefNo = b.Key.TruckNo,
        orders =
            (from c in b select new Order()
            {
                CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                TargetDate = c.TargetDate
            })
                .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.GroupBy` should be enough

```
var deliveries = orders.GroupBy(o => o.TruckNo)
    .Select(group => new Delivery 
        { 
            RefNo = group.Key, 
            Orders = group.Select(o => o).ToList()
        });
```